# Outlook 2016: How to delete all emails from specific sender that are in the Deleted folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I want to delete plenty of emails from the Deleted folder, but as there are thousands of them, when I search the Deleted folder it only returns 250 items from the server and I would hate to do this manually.

Is there is way to show more than 250 items to I can delete them at once?

I tried to increase the SearchResultsCap in the registry and increasing mail to keep offline, but neither helped.

Comment: I havce no outlook atm, so posting it as a comment, but in outlook 2010 you used to be able to click on a bar at the top of the emails which would sort them by whatever you clicked on. Data sent, **sender/name**, size  etc.

So sort on sent by/from, 
click on the top email to selected it,
Scroll down to the last email in the list and SHIFT-click it.

All email from the person should now be selected.
Press the delete key.

Presto. Done. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, the easiest way is to create a Search Folder. Create a custom search folder, specify only "Deleted Items" as a "Mail from these folders will be included in this Search Folder" and click the "Criteria..." button. There, you can select the required "From..." address and other conditions (if needed).

After that, you can delete all items from this search folder by just right-clicking it and selecting "Delete All" while holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key down.

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule in outlook and run it against your deleted folder:

1. Highlight an email that is an example of an email you would like to mass delete
2. Go to Rules -> Create Rule. Click on the advanced options button (lower right)
3. In the first window, check the box with "from ". Click next.
4. In this second window, check the box that says "permanently delete it". Click next
5. Don't select anything in this window. Click next
6. Uncheck the box that says "Turn on this rule". VERY IMPORTANT!! Click Finished
7. Selected your Deleted Items folder, and from the ribbon, go to Rules->Manage Rules and Alerts
8. Click on "Run Rules Now...", select the rule you just created.  Make sure the "Run in Folder" field is set to your Deleted Items folder. VERY IMPORTANT!! Then click run now

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this will not delete the server emails. It will only delete the top 250 emails, if I show them in advance and will not query for the rest of the mails from the server to execute the rule on them as well.